# how to set up ACL on a kafka topic using java api?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, acl, kafka-topic

I am trying to set up *acl* on Apache Kafka topics through Java. I came across the `setAcl()` method present in Kafka admin client. But not sure how to use it. I have a Kafka cluster set up with 3 brokers and *acl* is applied on it ( server side ).

I need to implement it in java on client side ( I have the required client certificates ).  Please Note that I need help with the java code ( not by using shell script)

Comment: You can take reference from here to understand. https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-security-0.9

Comment: @P3arl : I don't see the acl implementation part in this link

Comment: Refer to this doc... It specifies the method and classes required to use the AdminClient ans create ACL's using it. https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/KafkaAdminClient.html